# Selecting "Delete profile" clears selected item in dropdown; keyboard-only users cannot select most options in dropdown

Tags: bug, status-review, accessibility, contact, keyboard

There is a list of topics on [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact):

> [image: Topics]

If you select "I need to delete my user profile" the current selection will be cleared:

> [image: Cleared options]

Here's an animated GIF for some details:

> [image: GIF of myself selecting the "I need to delete my user profile" option then having the dropdown selection reset to "Please select a topic"]

This also presents a problem for keyboard-only users, as they cannot select any option in the dropdown other than "I lost my password" and "I need to add or remove login credentials". Steps to reproduce:

1. Hold the Tab key until the "Please select a topic" dropdown is highlighted.
2. Press the down arrow key to select the first option, "I lost my password". Press Esc to close the dialog. Repeat the same keystrokes to select the second option, "I need to add or remove login credentials".
3. Press the down arrow key a third time followed by Esc. The selection loops back to "Please select a topic". It's impossible to select other items in the dropdown.

As a temporary workaround, one can press the End key to select the last option in the dropdown, then press the up arrow key to scroll up from the bottom. However, the main issue here should still be fixed, since without this it's not possible to select any option aside from the top two using only the keyboard, making for poor UX.

Comment: I fail to see the bug here. "I need to delete my user profile" **is the selection**. Of course it will clear the previous selection. Being so trivial I really don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 the problem is that is you select to delete your profile, the drop-down reverts back to "Please select a topic"

Comment: @bobble of course, why won't it? You choose this as "what can we help you with" question. That's standard drop down behavior. It never "remember" previous selections, and adding such complex mechanism is just waste of dev time in my opinion. I prefer them fixing actual bugs.

Comment: @sha no, this happens before you submit. You select “I need to delete”, a pop up appears, and your selection is gone. This is different behaviour to other options in the drop down…

Comment: @Tim so the bug is that the "I need to delete" should appear as a button, or link outside of the drop down. (Because you don't send them any contact form about it) - that's just a very poor UX, pushing unrelated item into a drop down.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3 yes agreed, the UX is a strange choice. This could be a multi page wizard, not have the contact field on the page, like most other help pages I’ve used which redirect you away to self service opinions where they can.

Comment: This represents a usability issue for keyboard-only users. Once the dropdown is highlighted, they can only use the down arrow key for selecting the first two actual options, then it loops back to the top.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks for pointing the keyboard approach out. This is exactly how I discovered the issue.